# How to add custom class to <article> of genesis framework

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I am trying to add column classes of bootstrap in genesis child theme. I am not able to figure how to add those classes to  of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some more time, I figured it out.

In functions add,

```
//* Add custom classes to posts
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_entry', 'atp_post_class' );
function atp_post_class( $attributes ) {

    $attributes['class'] = 'col-md-4 ' . join( ' ', get_post_class() );

    if ( ! is_main_query() && ! genesis_is_blog_template() ) {
        return $attributes;
    }

    $attributes['itemscope'] = true;
    $attributes['itemtype']  = 'http://schema.org/CreativeWork';

    return $attributes;
}
```

Comment: `$attributes['class']` already contains the class string so you could change your attributes line to: `$attributes['class'] .= ' col-md-4';`